# Leaving a copy behind when using UIKit uk-sortable

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, uikit, vue-component

I'm integrating uk-sortable to my app beause I am using UIKit as the UI Framework for VueJS. I know there are other solutions out there (jQuery, Dragula, etc) I don't want to add another library for one thing. I'd rather get this to work instead.

Anyhow, the sortable works, I am able to drag and drop perfectly, however, I would like to leave a copy behind of whatever I am dragging.

The regular syntax is like this:

```
//From here
<div uk-sortable="group: my-group">
    <div>Drag this</div>
</div>

// To here
<div uk-sortable="group: my-group">
    <div>Drag this</div>
</div>
```

Note: The copy-behind must be only from one element (the origin element). If I drag from the destination back to the origin, it is a removal and no copy behind.

Here is a link for it

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/lotusms/4q75g3h6/9/)

Thanks in advance

Comment: your codepen is just a bare `uikit` implementation, without any `vue`. Just to be clear, are you expecting someone to build a vue project around this example?

Comment: @Daniel I turned the Codepen into a JSFiddle with Vue. You don't need me to load up an entire project for this. I believe this question is mostly pointed towards those who know what events can be used in UIKit, what they're called, and how to use them. Their documentation is vague.